# entity framework uses Datareader?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a simple question: if I have a simple EF query and I execute it, than it works like follows:

- it generates an sql query
- it runs the query against the database
- it fills the entity object list with data from a simple datareader?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like this. What else it can use? And why do you care?

Comment: Source code is here if you care to check https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, because I just want not only to use something, but to unterstand it too.